# How to list all deprecated classes to a file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, deprecated

I'm aware that Intellij [can scan](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206205679-Can-Intellij-code-analysis-find-all-instances-of-deprecated-code-in-a-project-directory-of-many-classes-?sort_by=votes) for this - and there seems to be an ancient project called [Scannotation](http://scannotation.sourceforge.net/). Neither of these seems to do what I want.

I want to list the full package names of classes in my codebase that are marked `@Deprecated`.

My question is: **How to list all deprecated classes to a file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can use:

```
    package util;

    import io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.FastClasspathScanner;
    import io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.matchprocessor.ClassAnnotationMatchProcessor;

    public class AnnotationScanTest {


        public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException {


            new FastClasspathScanner("com")
                    // Optional, in case you want to debug any issues with scanning.
                    // Add this right after the constructor to maximize the amount of log info.
                    .verbose()
                    // Add a MatchProcessor ("Mechanism 1")
                    .matchClassesWithAnnotation(Deprecated.class, new ClassAnnotationMatchProcessor() {
                        @Override
                        public void processMatch(Class<?> matchingClass) {
                            System.out.println("Matching annotation: " + matchingClass);
                        }
                    })
                    // Actually perform the scan (nothing will happen without this call)
                    .scan();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Structural Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html).

`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `A` --> `Search Structurally`

Use this to find all deprecated classes:

```
@Deprecated
class $class$ {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a unix/linux system you could use `find . -name *.java -regex "@Deprecated"`

This would give a list of files with absolute paths that could be changed to package notation with `sed` or any other text editor.

On Windows you might consider installing *git* which brings a bash where you can run this command.

Comment: Problem with this is, it will list files that have deprecated methods as well (not the whole class deprecated)

Comment: This is great - if you can modify it so it only does the ones before the class declaration it will be perfect.